# Permutations cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Why is$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
a cycle of length $3$, and
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2  \\
        2 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
a cycle of length $2$, but
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        2 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 3\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
is not a cycle at all?

Wouldn't the third permutation send $1$ to $2$ and $2$ back to $1$, completing the cycle of length $2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last one has two cycles, $(1\ 2)$ and $(3\ 4\ 5)$. It is not one singular cycle. In other words, it **has** cycles but **it is not itself** a cycle.

Comment: Permutations can have only one cycle?

Comment: @Allan They can have $\frac n2$ cycles at most, but it's only a cycle if it only has one cycle containing all the elements.

Comment: What about the first permutation? Doesn't that one complete its cycle without using elements $4$ and $5$?

Comment: @Allan It has a cycle. It is not itself a cycle.